# jQuery form validation with two validation messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

Client side [form validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) becomes easiest by using jQuery.

I tried all validators and they are so simple!

But in date, number and range validators; I need to add two validators in sequence

1. Required 2) Date

So is it possible?

Another common requirement is to **reset the Form Fields**. Is it possible using `jQuery` without writing too much code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can add many rules at once](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

As far as resetting the form, there is a method for this built into Javascript:

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Easiest way to add new rule is to write like class="date required"

Comment: jQuery has also function called $("#myForm").resetForm()

Which will also clean extra HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

Using two validators should not be an issue. Do you get an error?

Use the jQuery form plugin here : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api for reset functionality.

Comment: Recommending adding an entire plugin for a native DOM function? Questionable at best...

Comment: In my ASP.net page, the reset function wont work in Firefox. Not tested on any other browser though.

Comment: How are you calling it? I've tested it and it works fine on Firefox.